# Late 2009 iMac won't boot (mb950b/a)

Tags: imac, startup, ssd, recovery

This one has me beat!
I bought a used iMac a late 2009, mb950b/a. the story I got was it was all ok but after a fresh os install it stopped working, he has pics of it running an old os.

it will start and I get the apple logo and it tries to start then the status bar fills and nothing, it just sits there at the apple logo and a full status bar.

I ran AHT from a usb and it showed up no issues.

I created a bootable usb with El Capitan, when I select the usb with bootable usb, again apple logo and status bar.

I start from command + R, same apple logo and status bar.

I start from N, spinning work and same apple logo and status bar.

ive reset everything and same.

Ive installed a new SSD and tried to boot via bootable usb, same

Ive fitted another SSD from another iMac and again the same

I have tried loads of resets, swapping drives anything I can find, but nothing will work.

could it be still hardware and if so what?

so in short all i’m a getting is the apple logo and a status bar,
I can’t access startup recovery, Im lost with this one, any help please

Comment: Try single user mode

Comment: hi I can't enter single user mode as the hard drive is blank, if I plus in the USB with bootable OS I can, am I right in this?

Comment: Can you boot in verbose mode (CMD+V during boot) and share a slow-mo capture of the screen?